# How to get the difference between two dates?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I have two dates in format(MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:SS).  For the both dates I have converted the two dates to strings by using (stringFromDate) method. But I could not get the difference between them and show them in my console. Please give me an idea how I should get it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval dateTime;


if ([visitDate isEqualToDate:today])   //visitDate is a NSDate

{

NSLog (@"Dates are equal");

}

dateTime = ([visitDate timeIntervalSinceDate:today] / 86400);  

if(dateTime < 0) //Check if visit date is a past date, dateTime returns - val

{

NSLog (@"Past Date");

}

else 

{   
NSLog (@"Future Date");

}
```

Comment: I would recommend putting that magic number (86400) in a constant like this: `const CGFloat kSecondsPerDay  = 60 * 60 * 24;`..

Answer (score 2):

Keep the dates as dates, get the difference between them, then print the difference.

From the [docs on NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) and assuming **gregorian** is an NSCalendar:

```
NSDate *startDate = ...;

NSDate *endDate = ...;

unsigned int unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate  toDate:endDate  options:0];

int months = [comps month];

int days = [comps day];
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I see day delta calculations handled by converting day/year values into flat days (usually days since some starting [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)), like 01/01/1970).

To aid in this, I've found it helpful to create a table of days into the year that each month starts. Here's a class I used for this recently.

```
namespace {
    // Helper class for figuring out things like day of year
    class month_database {
    public:
        month_database () {

            days_into_year[0] = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
                days_into_year[i+1] = days_into_year[i] + days_in_month[i];
            }
        };

        // Return the start day of the year for the given month (January = month 1).
        int start_day (int month, int year) const {

            // Account for leap years. Actually, this doesn't get the year 1900 or 2100 right,
            // but should be good enough for a while.
            if ( (year % 4) == 0 && month > 2) {
                return days_into_year[month-1] + 1;
            } else {
                return days_into_year[month-1];
            }
        }
    private:
        static int const days_in_month[12];

        // # of days into the year the previous month ends
        int days_into_year[12];
    };
    // 30 days has September, April, June, and November...
    int const month_database::days_in_month[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30,   31, 30, 31, 31,   30, 31, 30, 31};

    month_database month;
}
```

As you can see from the `start_day` method, the main issue you are going to be wrestling with is how many leap days are contained in your range. Within our epoch the calculation I used there is good enough. The actual rule for which years contain leap days is [discussed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_day).

> February 29 in the Gregorian calendar,
>   the most widely used today, is a date
>   that occurs only once every four
>   years, in years evenly divisible by 4,
>   such as 1976, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008,
>   2012 or 2016 (with the exception of
>   century years not divisible by 400,
>   such as 1900).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the difference in days, you can do this. (Based on mihir mehta's answer.)

```
const NSTimeInterval kSecondsPerDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
- (NSInteger)daysUntilDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate {
    NSTimeInterval secondsUntilExpired = [self timeIntervalSinceDate:anotherDate];
    NSTimeInterval days = secondsUntilExpired / kSecondsPerDay;
    return (NSInteger)days;
}
```

Comment: (You should add this as a category method to NSDate.)